# Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties Validation

Tags: java, configuration, spring-boot

I know the possibilities of using JSR303 Annotation in Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties`, but I have some use cases exceeding this possibilities:

I have a `@ConfigurationProperties` Bean which enables my application to have a folder configured for backups. So I need to check if that folder exists and is writeable. If it doesn't exist I want to create it.

Right now I use an init-Method with `@PostConstruct` and it works fine. I just wonder if there is a more declarative way of validating a ConfigurationProperties-Class.

Comment: That imho isn't validation but part of your backup proces. Validation is if something has the right format, legal values, or isn't `null` (for configuration properties). What you want should be part of your backup proces and not the configuration, it should also work if you would configure the proces manually and not using the properties class.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use JSR-303 annotations to validate the state of the backup folder you could use [bean-validators](https://github.com/britter/bean-validators/). It's a library I've written a while ago with some additional validation annotations. It has file related annotations like [@Writable](http://britter.github.io/bean-validators/apidocs/com/github/britter/beanvalidators/file/Writable.html) which could be used to check the directory. But I agree with the comments: This should be part of the backup process, since the state of the directory could potentially change after the configuration has been loaded.